# Import CSV file Got "General system exception happened" Error

Tags: magento-2.1

**Steps to reproduce**

```
1.Login to Magento admin panel
2.Select "System" -> "Import"
3.Entity type = "products", Import Behaviour = "Add/Update" - "Stop on error"
4.Allowed errors count = "10", Field Seperator = ",", Multi value seperator ","
5.Select file to import = myfile, Image files directory = "pub/media/import/"
(Remove quotation marks).
```

**Expected result**

`.CSV` should be validated successfully, with `4065` lines (not including headers). Then the products should be imported successfully after clicking "Import"

**Actual result**

After uploading `.CSV`, I see a red "**General system exception happened**"

Please help me to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Please reduce on the number of rows. Spread them into different files. More like manual batch processing